# Autocomplete ahah combo is not working in Drupal 6

Tags: forms, ajax

I am using Drupal 6. 
I have a form which uses autocomplete and ahah in form. It works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome. if its just ahah or autocomplete it works fine but the combo seems to be not working in Chrome. :(
Below is my form

```
$form['my_fieldset']['my_field'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Something'),
      '#description' => $client_exists_text,
      '#autocomplete_path' => 'autocomplete/my_field',
      '#ahah' => array(
         'event' => 'change',
         'path' => ahah_helper_path(array('details_fields')),
         'wrapper' => 'details-fields',
         'method' => 'replace',
         'progress' => 'throbber',
      ),
      '#default_value' => ($form_state['values']['my_field']) ? ($form_state['values']['my_field']) : $client_data['my_field'],
```

Has anyone come accross such issue, please help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it working in one browser, but not another, it is a client side problem...ie. javascript. Check the console in Chrome for any errors

Comment: Hi 2pha, Thanks for replying. The Console says nothing. :(
please help!

Answer (score 0):

you need delete 'event' => 'change' or change event value

Comment: Hello. Could you explain why deleting that part would help? And for "change event value" - change it to what?